# How can I make index form resource route out of the middleware?

Tags: laravel

Now this route's without ( except ) it just find working but when I want to reach any route like index or store I must to login then get the data form them . So I want to make index route out of this middleware ( it's ok reach to index without login ) hope to got it :)

route's :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

Route::resource('cards', 'cardsController', ['except' => 'index']);

Route::resource('services', 'servicesController', ['except' => 'index']);

Route::get('getUserinfo', 'LoginController@getUser');

});
```

and this my route list for cards :

[image]

and this when I get all cards form postman :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `['except' => 'index']` in the route group. Try to take it out and check if it is working.

**Edited:**

if you want index showing without login, try writting another route outside of the route group

so something like this

```
Route::get('cards', 'cardsController@index');
Route::get('services', 'servicesController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

Route::resource('cards', 'cardsController', ['except' => 'index']);

Route::resource('services', 'servicesController', ['except' => 'index']);

Route::get('getUserinfo', 'LoginController@getUser');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should name your Controllers properly, instead of

`cardsController`

name it to

`CardsController`

Your error occurs because you are excepting the index action in your Controller.

Instead of this:

```
Route::resource('cards', 'cardsController', ['except' => 'index']);

Route::resource('services', 'servicesController', ['except' => 'index']);
```

Do this:

```
Route::resource('cards', 'cardsController');

Route::resource('services', 'servicesController');
```

Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Dont forget to name your Controller properly.

Comment: @ahmed did you try it, you need to provide more informationen, what happened after removing the except statement?

Comment: it's working without except but I need to make index showing without login

Comment: @ahmed what exactly do you mean, can you explain it further

Answer (score 0):

As you should define your route outside the middleware.... As u want to use it without login....

```
Route::get('cards', 'cardsController@index');
Route::get('services', 'servicesController@index');
```

In middleware u have to define the route as below

```
Route::resource('cards', 'cardsController')->except('index');

Route::resource('services', 'servicesController')->except('index');
```